# Counting num_rows issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM configurations WHERE ID = userID
```

I then have logic like this:

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

foreach($query->result() as $row) { 
// display data
}

else {

// display no data found message

}
```

But when I try to do this:

```
count($query->num_rows())
```

it is always 1, no matter how many results are returned.  If 1 or more are returned the "if" is executed.  If there are no results returned the "else" is executed.  Yet, the count never changes.  What is going on?

Comment: num_rows() returns a single numeric value (the number of rows is only a single number) not an array, so there is only 1 value for count() to count... num_rows() __is__ the number of results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `count()` a number, it works fine. If you only want number of records from table use `COUNT()` in SQL...

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(0) AS count FROM configurations WHERE ID = userID");
$sql = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
$count = $sql["count"];
```

Otherwise just assign `$count = $query->num_rows();` as **@chriso** stated.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly `else {` should be `} else {` - you're missing a brace

Secondly, `count()` is used to count the number of elements in an array. Since `$query->num_rows()` returns a number rather than an array, you don't need to use `count()`. In your case, count() was telling you that there's one number, not what the actual number was!

Try:

```
$count = $query->num_rows();
echo $count;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an integer with **$query->num_rows()**, so when you run that integer through the **count()** function it is designed to return 1.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

> If var is not an array or an object
> with implemented Countable interface,
> 1 will be returned. There is one
> exception, if var is NULL, 0 will be
> returned.